# How to upload image to Azure Blob storage

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I read and found that the best way to upload images is using blob storage.  I want to use it with node.js.  How can I upload for example an image to blob using node.js code?

Comment: Refer to this sdk sample.https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node#blob-storage

Comment: I saw that its work with local file.
What if I want that user can upload image as a client and this image send to the server (node.js).then the server upload it to blob
what i need to use in the server?

Comment: Suppose you could upload imge to stream then use `createPageBlobFromStream`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Blob with nodejs, there is release package to implement it. It's a Node.js package and a browser compatible JavaScript Client Library that makes it easy to consume and manage Microsoft Azure Storage Services.

Further more details you could refer to this github page:[Azure Storage SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node#microsoft-azure-storage-sdk-for-nodejs-and-javascript-for-browsers). And you could upload local file to blob directly with `createBlockBlobFromLocalFile`.

Also you could upload file into stream the create the blob. If you want some sample you could refer to the below code.

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var blobService = azure.createBlobService("connection string");
blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('mycontainer', 'taskblob', 'task1-upload.txt', function(error, result, response) {
  if (!error) {
    // file uploaded
  }
});
```

Beside this, you could refer to the official tutorial about the Azure Blob nodejs:[using the client library for Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs).

Comment: @עידן עובדיה, could you solve it? If this could help you, you could accept it as the answer. And if you still have problem, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below-listed SDK's

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node#microsoft-azure-storage-sdk-for-nodejs-and-javascript-for-browsers
[image]

If you are not modifying existing code and writing from scratch better you use the first one(Storage SDK v10 for javascript). You can refer my code below :

```
const {
    Aborter, BlobURL,
    BlockBlobURL, ContainerURL,
    ServiceURL,
    StorageURL,
    SharedKeyCredential,
    generateBlobSASQueryParameters,
    uploadStreamToBlockBlob,
    BlobSASPermissions,
    SASProtocol,
    AnonymousCredential,
} = require("@azure/storage-blob");

const STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = process.env.STORAGE_ACCOUNT;
const ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY = process.env.STORAGE_KEY;
const AS = {};    // Azure Storage
console.log(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME);
/*
const ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
const FOUR_MEGABYTES = 4 * ONE_MEGABYTE;
const ONE_MINUTE = 60 * 1000;
By default, credential is always the last element of pipeline factories
const factories = serviceURL.pipeline.factories;
const sharedKeyCredential = factories[factories.length - 1];
*/

AS.getServiceUrl = () => {
    const credentials = new SharedKeyCredential(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY);
    const pipeline = StorageURL.newPipeline(credentials);
    const serviceURL = new ServiceURL(`https://${STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net`, pipeline);
    return serviceURL;
}

AS.createBlockBlobSASToken = (blobName, containerName, options) => {
    const now = new Date();
    now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() - 5); // Skip clock skew with server
    const tmr = new Date();
    tmr.setDate(tmr.getDate() + 1);
    const credentials = new SharedKeyCredential(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY);
    const blobSAS = generateBlobSASQueryParameters(
        {
            blobName,
            containerName,
            expiryTime: tmr,
            permissions: BlobSASPermissions.parse("racwd").toString(),
            protocol: SASProtocol.HTTPSandHTTP,
            startTime: now,
        },
        credentials
    );
    //const sasURL = `${blobURL.url}?${blobSAS}`;
    return blobSAS
}


AS.createContainerSASToken = (containerName, options) => {
    const now = new Date();
    now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() - 5); // Skip clock skew with server
    const tmr = new Date();
    tmr.setDate(tmr.getDate() + 1);
    const credentials = new SharedKeyCredential(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY);
    const containerSAS = generateBlobSASQueryParameters(
        {
            containerName,
            expiryTime: tmr,
            permissions: ContainerSASPermissions.parse("racwdl").toString(),
            protocol: SASProtocol.HTTPSandHTTP,
            startTime: now,
            version: "2016-05-31"
        },
        credentials
    );
    // const sasURL = `${containerURL.url}?${containerSAS}`;
    return containerSAS;
}

AS.createBlockBlobSASURL = (blobName, containerName) => {
    let blockBlobURL = getBlockBlobUrl(blobName, containerName);
    let blobSAS = createBlockBlobSASToken(blobName, containerName);
    const sasURL = `${blockBlobURL.url}?${blobSAS}`;
    return sasURL;
}

AS.createContainer = (containerName) => {
    const serviceURL = getServiceUrl();
    const containerURL = ContainerURL.fromServiceURL(serviceURL, containerName);
    return containerURL.create(Aborter.none);
}

AS.getBlockBlobUrl = (blobName, containerName) => {
    const serviceURL = getServiceUrl();
    const containerURL = ContainerURL.fromServiceURL(serviceURL, containerName);
    const blockBlobURL = BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, blobName);
    return blockBlobURL;
}

AS.uploadToBlockBlobFromStream = (blobName, containerName, readableStream, fileSizeInBytes) => {
    const blockBlobURL = getBlockBlobUrl(blobName, containerName);
    return uploadStreamToBlockBlob(Aborter.none,
        readableStream,
        blockBlobURL,
        256 * 1024,
        2,
        {
            progress: function (ev) {
                console.log((ev.loadedBytes / fileSizeInBytes) * 100);
            }
        }
    )
}

// const uploadFileFromBuffer = (blobName, containerName,buffer, fileSizeInBytes) =>{


// }

AS.uploadBlockBlobWithSAS = (blobName, containerName, readableStream, fileSizeInBytes) => {
    const blockBlobSasUrl = createBlockBlobSASURL(blobName, containerName);
    let blockBlobURL = new BlockBlobURL(blockBlobSasUrl, StorageURL.newPipeline(new AnonymousCredential()))
    return uploadStreamToBlockBlob(Aborter.none,
        readableStream,
        blockBlobURL,
        4 * 1024 * 1024,
        2,
        {
            progress: function (ev) {
                console.log((ev.loadedBytes / fileSizeInBytes) * 100);
            }
        }
    )
}

AS.deleteBlockBlob = (blobName, containerName) => {
    const blockBlobURL = getBlockBlobUrl(blobName, containerName);
    return blockBlobURL.delete(Aborter.none)

}

AS.downloadBlob = async (blobName, containerName) => {
    const blockBlobURL =  await getBlockBlobUrl(blobName, containerName);
    const downloadStream = await blockBlobURL.download(aborter, 0);
    return downloadStream;
}

module.exports = AS;
```